# ¿“Como si” con indicativo?

Tags: subjuntivo, conjunciones

En un libro de gramática española he leído que "en el lenguaje descuidado" el verbo de la oración subordinada después de la conjunción comparativa *como si* puede tener la forma indicativa. Me gustaría saber la opinión de los hablantes nativos. ¿De verdad usaríais el modo indicativo en oraciones de **comparación irreal**? A mí me suena raro:

> Hacen como si no *se conocen*.

Yo diría:

> Hacen como si no *se conocieran*.

Y vosotros, ¿qué diríais?

Answer (score 2):

No diría que las formas:

> 1. Hacen como si no se conocen.
> 2. Hacen como que no se conocen.

son manifestaciones de un lenguaje descuidado.

En realidad, son tan correctas y usadas como:

> 3. Hacen como si no se conocieran.
> 4. Hacen como que no se conocieran.

En todos los casos, las personas se conocen pero fingen que no.

La única diferencia que podría haber es que (1) y (2) pueden considerarse algo más coloquiales que (3) y (4).

Más allá de mi opinión como hablante nativo, existe bibliografía (ver por ejemplo https://www.practicaespanol.com/las-expresiones-como-que-y-como-si/) de acuerdo con la cual "como que" es coloquial y se utiliza siempre con indicativo, mientras que "como si" es más culto y se utiliza siempre con subjuntivo.

Mi conclusión es que la coloquialidad del verbo "hacer" hace que el indicativo sea de uso corriente en expresiones como (1), pero no con otros verbos. Así, (5) no me resulta aceptable:

> 5. ?* Actúan como si no se conocen.

Debe decirse:

> 6. Actúan como si no se conocieran.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Pregunté a cuatro españoles y me dijeron que preferirían la versión „Hacen como si no se conocieran“. ¿Puede ser que colegas transatlánticos prefieran „Hacen como si no se conocen.“?

Comment: @Aurora No diría que lo preferimos sino que nos resulta más coloquial, como si "hacer como si" o "hacer como que" fuera equivalente a "fingir que". Nótese que ese "hacer" es prácticamente un verbo vacío de contenido. Con verbos semánticamente más ricos, se impone el subjuntivo.

Answer (score 2):

Como comparación irreal no, pero sí para indiferencia.

> Por mí, como si se marcha.

Sin embargo, la comparación irreal con indicativo no me convence, porque si es irreal, debería utilizar el subjuntivo.